# vim should auto commit on quit using git or fugitive(?)

Tags: git, vim, github, versioning, vim-fugitive

I´m new to git and  I´ve a little problem using git the way I want to. 
I administrate a bunch of servers. 
What I want to have is a local repository of the config files I edit. In case of missconfiguratin I could then easily jump back to a working version.

For example:
I edit a file that is not in the repository. After editing I would like to add it to the repo automatically including the absolute path and do the commit. The commit message should be asked automatically on quit.

Until now I tried it using this additional line in vimrc.local:

```
autocmd BufWritePost * let message = input('Message? ', 'Auto-commit: saved ' . 
expand('%')) | execute ':silent ! if git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1 ; 
then git add % ; git commit -m ' . shellescape(message, 1) . '; fi > /dev/null 2>&1'
```

Source: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748286/vimrc-auto-commit-w-message-prompt)

This does not solve my problem as the files are not included with their absolute path and sometimes are not added at all.

I heard about fugitive which could do that but I don´t get it working this way.

I think I am not the first one having this problem. Could anyone explain me how to set this up step by step. Please consider that I am new to this topic.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: Making a commit every time you save a file is _not_ a good idea. With configuration files, it is desirable to have each commit represent a _correctly working_ state of the configuration. So in general, you want to commit changes only _after_ you've tested them. Additionally, it is customary to give every commit an sensible commit message that summarizes the changes.

Answer (score 1):

In the long run, I think you will be more productive if you get fugitive to work.  I find `:Gdiff` invaluable.

I do not like the style of long one-liners in vim.  If I *want* to get dizzy, I will stare at regular expressions.  I would break up your autocommand as follows to make it easier to understand and update:

```
autocmd BufWritePost * call AutoGitCommit()

function! AutoGitCommit()
  let message = input('Message? ', 'Auto-commit: saved ' . expand('%'))
  let message = shellescape(message, 1)
  let shellcommand = 'if git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1 ; '
  let shellcommand .= 'then git add ' . expand('%:p') . ' ; '
  let shellcommand .= 'git commit -m ' . message . '; '
  let shellcommand .= 'fi > /dev/null 2>&1'
  execute ':silent!' shellcommand
endfun
```

Since the file name is now in a String context, <kbd>%</kbd> will no longer be expanded automatically, so I use `escape()`.  I added the `:p` modifier since you asked for the absolute path.  See `:help expand()` and `:help filename-modifiers`.

In fact, my preference would be to let vim handle the conditional, like so:

```
function! AutoGitCommit()
  call system('git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1')
  if v:shell_error
    return
  endif
  let message = input('Message? ', 'Auto-commit: saved ' . expand('%'))
  call system('git add ' . expand('%:p'))
  call system('git commit -m ' . shellescape(message, 1))
endfun
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why in my case fugitive would be the better way?
Tomorow I will have a try with both ways and let you know about my results.

Comment: I do not know that fugitive will help with this particular task.  I do know that fugitive is well thought out.  It is better to take advantage of the work Tim Pope has already put into it than to start from scratch yourself.